# Unable to add headers to my request API in Angular7

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, http-post

I am unable to set headers to my request URL. Request has to send the upload file object, request JSON and headers required for authorization. The request doesn't append with the headers so the api sending me 401 unauthorized response back. Mine is a Angular 7 Application. I am using @angular/http for header building. Please find html & ts the code below.

Any quick fix will helps me a lot.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="font-weight-bold text-center pageSpacing">
        Thanks America <img src="assets/images/add-icon.png"
            style="width: 3%; float: right;" class="pointer"
            (click)="openWindowCustomClass(content)">
    </div>
 <ng-template #content let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="pointer" (click)="fileInputImage.click()">
            <img src="assets/images/upload-image_80.png" style="width: 25%;">Upload
            Image
        </div>
        <div class="pointer" (click)="fileInputVideo.click()">
            <img src="assets/images/upload-video_80.png" style="width: 25%;">Upload
            Video
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <span
            style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0">
            <input type="file" #fileInputImage accept='image/*'
            (click)="isUpload='i'" (change)="preview(fileInputImage.files)"
            ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
        </span> <span
            style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0">
            <input type="file" #fileInputVideo accept='video/*'
            (click)="isUpload='v'" (change)="preview(fileInputVideo.files)"
            ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"
        style="border-top: 0px; justify-content: center;">
        <form [formGroup]="commentPopup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea type="text" rows="5" maxlength="400"
                    formControlName="comment" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter your comment here"
                    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.comment.errors }"></textarea>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"
                    (click)="modal.close('Close click');clearPreview();">Cancel</button>
                &nbsp;
                <button (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" class="btn btn-primary"
                    [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </ng-template>
```

**TS file Code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {  FileUploader, FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';

constructor(private httpService: HttpClient, private modalService: NgbModal, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
     this.isUpload = '';
    }

    openWindowCustomClass(content) {
        this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'sm' });
    }
      validation() {
        this.commentPopup = this.formBuilder.group({
            comment: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }
    get f() { return this.commentPopup.controls; }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.commentPopup.invalid) {
            return;
        }
    }

preview(files) {
        if (files.length === 0)
            return;

        var mimeType = files[0].type;
        if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null && mimeType.match(/video\/*/) == null) {
            this.message = "Only images / videos are supported.";
            return;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        this.imageOrVideoPath = files;
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        reader.onload = (_event) => {
            this.imgOrVideoURL = reader.result;
        }
    }
    clearPreview() {
        this.validation();
        this.imgOrVideoURL = null;
        this.imageOrVideoPath = null;
        this.comment = null;
        this.isUpload='';
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.fileUpload();
        this.validation();
    }



      public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: this.imageUploadUrl, headers:this.headers,  method: 'POST' });
            fileUpload() {
 this.authHeaders.headers = [{ name: 'userId', value: '1234' },
            { name: 'deviceKey', value: '9999-8888-7777' }];

                this.uploader.onBuildItemForm = (item, form) => {
                    form.append("content","TESTING");
                    form.append("author", "username");
                };
                 this.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem  = (item) => { 

        this.uploader.setOptions(this.authHeaders); 
                  };
                this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => { file.withCredentials = false; };
                this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
                    console.log('ImageUpload:uploaded:', item, status, response);
                    if (status === 200) {
                        alert('File uploaded successfully');
                        this.uploadedResponse = response;
                    } else {
                        alert("something went wrong");
                    }
                };
            }
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for your problem, its helps to solve quickly

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this,

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Declare Header option like this.

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000'})
};
const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/customer";
```

and use this header options likethis

```
  getBook(id: string): Observable<any> {
const url = `${apiUrl}/${id}`;
return this.http.get(url, httpOptions).pipe(
  map(this.extractData),
  catchError(this.handleError));
 }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`FileUploader` option is not a `Headers` in `@angular/http` but just an array of simple objects with name and value properties.

Do something like this:

```
...
this.headers = [
  {name: 'userInfoId', value: '1'},
  {name: 'deviceKey', value: '5555-00-90p0'},
]
public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: this.imageUploadUrl, headers:this.headers,  method: 'POST' });
...
```

Comment: I tried this but I am able to see the headers name but not values in request ie., userInfoId, deviceKey . I am unable to understand whats going wrong.  Any idea. One more thing does the ng2-file-upload can't accept the headers as json instead as array. Thats where the probelem araise i think.

Comment: @Madhavi can you update your post with what you tried?

Comment: I edited my post ie., added this.authHeaders in ts file.